# How to maintain dictionary element order in JSON dump in Python

Tags: python, json

Due to a very helpful person on this site, I have been able to put together a script which takes user names (inputted by user) and then use a loop to append each of those user names to a specific JSON structure. However, I have noticed that the order within my JSON dump is not maintained. For example, here is what my loop and JSON dump looks like:

```
list_users = []
for user in users:
    list_users.append({"name": user,
                       "member": 123,
                       "comment": "this is a comment"})

json_user_list_encoding = json.dumps(list_users, indent=2)
```

My print looks like this:

```
({"member": 123,
  "comment": "this is a comment"
  "name": user
  })
```

I was wondering if it was possible to maintain the same order in "list_users" when I use the JSON dump. I have looked at this site a bit and from what I have read, I will have to assign keys in order to maintain a specific order. However, I am not sure how to do this being that I only have one JSON object. I hope this make sense. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Dictionary elements are inherently an unordered data structure. `{"a": 1, "b": 2}` is exactly the same as `{"b": 2, "a": 1}` -- they'll pass an equality check, &c.

Comment: why do you need ordering?

Comment: ...which is to say, even if you **did** assign the keys yourself (`d={}; d["a"]=1; d["b"]=2`), you'd **still** have no ordering guarantees, because the assignment order and the storage/output order have no relationship between them guaranteed by documented semantics (whether there's a relationship *in practice* depends on hashing algorithm details that are implementation-defined).

Comment: As of Python 3.6, `dict` *does* maintain the order that the keys are inserted. For portability, you can use `collections.OrderedDict`. However I agree with the above commenters, if a `dict` is the correct structure, there's probably no need for ordered entries.

Comment: Json is not ordered, python dictionaries are not ordered. If your purpose is to make the order predictable, so that (for example) the Json file can be usefully put into source control, then any order will do.

Comment: @BallpointBen  Python 3.6 dict doesn't maintain the order that keys are inserted.  **CPython** 3.6 dict does.  Python 3.6 only says that keyword arguments will arrive in order in the `kwargs` mapping.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification

Answer (score 8):

If you just want them ordered reliably/repeatably, but don't care about the order itself, then `json` dumps accepts a `sort_keys` kwarg that can help:

```
>>> json.dumps({'z': 3, 'b': 2, 'a': 1})
'{"a": 1, "z": 3, "b": 2}'
>>> json.dumps({'z': 3, 'b': 2, 'a': 1}, sort_keys=True)
'{"a": 1, "b": 2, "z": 3}'
```

Otherwise, put the users in an `OrderedDict` instead of a plain dict.

```
from collections import OrderedDict

list_users.append(OrderedDict([
    ("name", user),
    ("member", 123),
    ("comment", "this is a comment"),
]))
```

If you need them to *deserialize* to the same order too, use the [`object_pairs_hook`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.load) when loading.

Comment: Excellent point -- and if the input file is generated a shell script or such that supports `jq`, *that* has an option available for sorting keys as well.

Comment: Ah ok... yes that makes sense. Thanks!